# Sum of products in a single row

Tags: google-sheets

Here is the general structure of my spreadsheet:

```
Start End   Total X1 Y1 X2 Y2 X3 Y3 ... Xn Yn
09:00 10:00 1560  20 15 10 30 12 80

Total = X1 * Y1 + X2 * Y2 + X3 * Y3 ... Xn + Yn
```

[The `SUMPRODUCT` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294) does this but it requires multiple rows of data. I need the products to match up with their corresponding `Start` and `End` time records and this proved to be extremely difficult when they are spread over many rows.

Is there a way I can use `SUMPRODUCT` with an unlimited number of columns instead of rows?

Answer (score 1):

In [File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FNjvgBrMKgUAIeDqp4t8FJVqaByiEin_PgvDmsXEpMw/edit#gid=1054966493) in cell *C2* there is following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  SUMPRODUCT(
   FILTER($D2:$AA2,ISODD(SEQUENCE(1,COUNT($D2:$AA2),1,1))=TRUE),
   FILTER($D2:$AA2,ISODD(SEQUENCE(1,COUNT($D2:$AA2),1,1))=FALSE)))
```

Where $D1:$AA2 is supposed to be range of your data for Xn Yn so you can insert columns and range will expand.